# How to drawing on screen and convert it to character?

Tags: ios, drawing, character

I want to write a app that can drawing on the screen(or view) then convert it to be a character. 
IE: drawing a circle then the label appear "O"
drawing "N" shape and the label appear "N"/ "n"

Can anyone give me some advice??? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will have to keep noting the locations of touch when the user is drawing. That is note it from touch-down event to the touch-up event.
2. Then, you'll have to iterate through the points and understand the pattern.
3. The approach to understand the drawing patterns for letters/characters is known as OCR.
   OCR = Optical Character Recognition.
4. You'll have to either write your own OCR code or search for some readily available OCR from internet.

I hope you get the direction.. :)

Comment: you can select the tick of the answer, if it was helpful. It helps us increase reptutation. Thanks. :)